# HtmlUnit Driver not able to pick correct URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, headless-browser, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to implement headless testing so used HtmlUnit Driver for that. It is  working fine but fails on `assert` statement when I try to compare actual URL and expected URL. When I use HtmlUnit Driver, it picks up # at the end of URLs due to which condition fails although if I run on Firefox or chrome, works fine.

Comment: PLease share ur code

Comment: my code is
   
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
   driver.get("http://testurl/apply/");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   String exptUrl="http://exptUrl/help-with-travel";
  String actUrl=hook.getHelpWtTravelPage().getPageUrl();
  try {
   Assert.assertEquals(actUrl, exptUrl);

Comment: I am using same with google URL it show me same result in firefox and htmlunitdriver

Comment: I don't found any issue, Please share specific problem or error

Comment: As you see below html driver picks up "#" due to which it fails although i tried Thread.sleep, still fails.java.lang.AssertionError: http://citizen.blue.dev.nonprod.health.iosdigital.net:3000/apply/help-with-travel# - actual ur is not same as expt help with travel page url - http://citizen.blue.dev.nonprod.health.iosdigital.net:3000/apply/help-with-travel
 at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
 at com.atwApply.stepDefinations.HelpWithTravelSteps.verifyHelpWithTravelPageDspld(HelpWithTravelSteps.java:28)
 at ✽.Then helpWithTravel page is displayed(a_viewSubmittedApplication.feature:10)

Comment: Then it is not possible match it assertequal , you have to used contains command for thar

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code which I have tried in `Firefox` and `HtmlUnitDriver` which is working fine:

```
@Test
public void Login()
{

    // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver=new HtmlUnitDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     String actualURl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
     Assert.assertEquals(actualURl, "https://www.google.co.in/");

}}
```